# how to use python-gitlab to upload file with newline?

Tags: python, gitlab

I'm trying to use python-gitlab `projects.files.create` to upload a string content to gitlab.

The string contains `'\n'` which I'd like it to be the real newline char in the gitlab file, but it'd just write `'\n'` as a string to the file, so after uploading, the file just contains one line.

I'm not sure how and at what point should I fix this, I'd like the file content to be as if I print the string using `print()` in python.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT---

Sorry, I'm using python 3.7 and the string is actually a csv content, so it's basically like:

`',col1,col2\n1,data1,data2\n'`

So when I upload it the gitlab file I want it to be:

`,col1,col2
1,data1,data2`

Comment: It'll make it a lot easier for others to help you find where you did wrong if you posted your current code that you're having problems with. Try to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, post other relevant info like whether you are on Python 2 or Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out by saving the string to a file and read it again, this way the \n in the string will be translated to the actual newline char.

I'm not sure if there's other of doing this but just for someone that encounters a similar situation.